# Zero interactions with verify with Argument Captor for JMS test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, jms

I have a `void` method that sends a message to a JMS queue, and I am trying to write a test to test the text message that is sent to the queue.

Here is the code excerpt of the publish method in my service:

```java
try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(smiQueue.getUserName(), smiQueue.getPassword())) {
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue(trade.getEnvironment() + "." + trade.getQueueName());
    MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);
    TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(trade.getTradeContent());

    messageProducer.send(textMessage);

    messageProducer.close();
    session.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the integration test for that logic:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8084, stubs = "classpath:wiremock/mappings", files = "classpath:wiremock/")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ActiveProfiles("TEST")
class MyServiceIntegrationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    MessageProducer messageProducer;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<TextMessage> textMessageCaptor;

    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();

    @Test
    @DisplayName("should publish to queue")
    void shouldPublishToQueue() throws Exception {
        myService.publish(TestUtil.getTrade());

        verify(messageProducer).send(textMessageCaptor.capture());
        TextMessage textMessage = textMessageCaptor.getValue();
        assertEquals(TestUtil.getTrade().getTradeContent(), textMessage.getText());
    }
}
```

The test fails and I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
    org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport#0 bean.send(
        <any javax.jms.TextMessage>
    );
    -> at MyServiceIntegrationTest.shouldPublishToQueue(MyServiceIntegrationTest.java:81)
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

The `main` function is working as expected, and my message is posted to the queue, but the verify in the test says that there were no interactions.